# .NET Core WebSocket (using HttpListener) over Apache - I get 404 instead 101

Tags: c#, apache, .net-core, websocket

I made a WebSocket server using .NET Core. It uses `HttpListener` listening on `http://127.0.0.1:54321`.
When I connect to that server locally using URL `ws://127.0.0.1:54321` it works.
I tested that on both Windows and Linux machines.

Then I configured my Apache service to proxy it outside, to my domain.

So here's my virtual host configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:*>
    RequestHeader set "X-Forwarded-Proto" expr=%{REQUEST_SCHEME}
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} =websocket [NC]
    RewriteRule /(.*)           ws://127.0.0.1:54321/$1 [P,L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} !=websocket [NC]
    RewriteRule /(.*)           http://127.0.0.1:54321/$1 [P,L]
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPass / ws://127.0.0.1:54321/ 
    ProxyPassReverse / ws://127.0.0.1:54321/
    ServerName app.test.net
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/app.test.net-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/app.test.net-access.log common
</VirtualHost>
```

I connect my client to `ws://app.test.net/` and receive following exception:

> System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketException (997):
> The server returned status code '404' when status code '101' was expected.

What's weird, the traffic passes through, so it's 404 not 500. So it looks like the client and server see each other, but they can't make the upgrade from HTTP to WS.

Is there something wrong with my virtual host configuration, or something else must be changed in my dotnet app to work over the Apache.

Here's basic demo code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.WebSockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebSocketTest {
    
    class Program {
        
        static async Task Main(string[] args) {
            if (args != null && args.Length > 0) {
                switch (args[0]) {
                    case "server":
                        Console.WriteLine("Starting server...");
                        await StartServerAsync();
                        break;
                    case "client":
                        Console.WriteLine("Starting client...");
                        await StartClientAsync();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        static async Task StartServerAsync() {
            using var httpListener = new HttpListener();
            httpListener.Prefixes.Add("http://127.0.0.1:54321/");
            httpListener.Start();
            var receiveBuffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(new byte[1024]);
            while (true) {
                var httpContext = httpListener.GetContext();
                if (httpContext.Request.IsWebSocketRequest) {
                    var webSocketContext = await httpContext.AcceptWebSocketAsync(null);
                    if (webSocketContext.WebSocket.State == WebSocketState.Open) {
                        var receiveResult = await webSocketContext.WebSocket.ReceiveAsync(receiveBuffer, CancellationToken.None);
                        if (receiveResult.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Close) {
                            await webSocketContext.WebSocket.CloseOutputAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, null, CancellationToken.None);
                            await webSocketContext.WebSocket.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, null, CancellationToken.None);
                            return;
                        }
                        await webSocketContext.WebSocket.SendAsync(receiveBuffer.Slice(0, receiveResult.Count), WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        static async Task StartClientAsync() {
            var webSocket = new ClientWebSocket();
            var sendBuffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("hello"));
            var receiveBuffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(new byte[1024]);
            await webSocket.ConnectAsync(new Uri("ws://127.0.0.1:54321"), CancellationToken.None);
            await webSocket.SendAsync(sendBuffer, WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None);
            var receiveResult = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(receiveBuffer, CancellationToken.None);
            if (receiveResult.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Close) {
                await webSocket.CloseOutputAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, null, CancellationToken.None);
                await webSocket.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, null, CancellationToken.None);
                return;
            }
            var receivedText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(receiveBuffer.Slice(0, receiveResult.Count));
            Console.WriteLine(receivedText);
            await webSocket.CloseOutputAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, null, CancellationToken.None);
            await webSocket.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, null, CancellationToken.None);
        }

    }

}
```

Create new .NET Core 3.1 project, paste, no dependencies. Run with either "server" or "client" parameter. Both client and server won't exit, press Ctrl+C to stop them. I know, the code is very rough withouot proper shutdown procedure, but it doesn't matter. It listens for WebSocket connections and echoes whatever it gets from the client. The client sends "hello" and writes the response to the console. So it outputs "hello". That is - on local machine. Put the server over Apache on remote machine and it won't work. So...

I've seen Blazor and other ASP.NET Core apps used special configuration options like "use forwarded headers", but this is not ASP. IDK what else should I do beside setting up the `HttpListener`? Isn't it supposed to handle the handshaking by itself? Does it require a special configuration? IDK, I spent a couple of hours on it, tested everything I found in Google, but nothing works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the working Apache virtual host configuration in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`

```
<VirtualHost *:*>
    RequestHeader set "X-Forwarded-Proto" expr=%{REQUEST_SCHEME}
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:UPGRADE} ^WebSocket$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:CONNECTION} Upgrade$ [NC]
    RewriteRule /(.*) ws://127.0.0.1:54321/$1 [P]
    SSLProxyEngine On
    ProxyPreserveHost Off
    ProxyPass / ws://127.0.0.1:54321/
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:54321/
    ProxyPassReverse / ws://127.0.0.1:54321/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:54321/
    ServerName app.test.net
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/app.test.net-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/app.test.net-access.log common
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.star.test.net/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.star.test.net/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

The critical part here is `ProxyPreserveHost Off` - it's `On` in all examples I've seen. Especially - for Blazor. Now that I read:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypreservehost

> When enabled, this option will pass the Host: line from the incoming
> request to the proxied host, instead of the hostname specified in the
> ProxyPass line.
>
> This option should normally be turned Off. It is mostly useful in
> special configurations like proxied mass name-based virtual hosting,
> where the original Host header needs to be evaluated by the backend
> server.

It's default `Off`, and it should be `Off` for the basic WebSocket server, unless the server handles all proxy headers by itself. I guess it's what the ASP stack does, but I don't like it, I mean - let the proxy do the proxy thing.

Comment: Thanks! Apache was forwarding localhost rather than my subdomain.